# MySQL: Using JOINS with WHERE clause to get all records from one table and available records from the other

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, having-clause

I am tryin to run a SQL query as below

```
SELECT organization.idorganization,
organization.name,
organization.image_url,
organization.website,
organization.description,
organization.phone,
organization.email,
organization.spare_parts_items,
organization.specialty_vehicles,
organization.on_the_spot_service,
organization.home_visits,
organization.latitude,
organization.longitude,
organization.no_of_views,
 organization.is_disabled,
organization.date_created,
organization.last_update,
organization.address,
cover_photo.idcover_photo,
cover_photo.image_url,
cover_photo.thumbnail,
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(7.294324) ) * cos( radians( organization.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( organization.longitude ) - radians(80.646185) ) 
+ sin( radians(7.294324) ) * sin( radians( organization.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM organization 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cover_photo ON cover_photo.idcover_photo = organization.idorganization
WHERE organization.idorganization_type =1 HAVING distance < 20 AND cover_photo.thumbnail=true
```

Here, my expectation is to get all records from `organization` whether it has `cover_photo`s or not. Thats why I have used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. But, if it has `cover_photo`s, it should get only those which is a `thumbnail`. The `cover_photo` contains more than one photo for each `organization`.

When I run my code, I do not get what I am looking for. If there is no `thumbnails` available in `cover_photo` table, that particular `organization` is completely ignored. At this moment I have no `cover_photo` for any organization, so what I get is no results.

How to fix this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222811/discussion-on-question-by-lemon-juice-mysql-using-joins-with-where-clause-to-ge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to move the condition on the `LEFT JOIN`ed table from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`: otherwise, it becomes mandatory, and filters out rows where the `LEFT JOIN` did not match.

That is, change this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN cover_photo 
    ON  cover_photo.idcover_photo = organization.idorganization
WHERE organization.idorganization_type = 1 AND cover_photo.thumbnail = true
HAVING distance < 20
```

To:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN cover_photo 
    ON  cover_photo.idcover_photo = organization.idorganization
    AND cover_photo.thumbnail = true
WHERE organization.idorganization_type = 1 
HAVING distance < 20
```

Comment: I tried this. Thank you. The issue is, I noticed some `cover_photo` are getting mixed! That means, organizatins get wrong cover photos!

Comment: @LemonJuice: all I did was fixed the logic of your query, which is what your question was focusing on. I don't know your data (and you did not show it), so I cannot tell what the problem is here. Maybe you need to review the join conditions.

Comment: Okay. From my end, what do you need more? The query to build the tables? Let me know, I will post them

Comment: @LemonJuice: I think the question you asked here was answered. You might want to ask a new question, providing sample data, current and desired results (and possibly simplifying the query a bit - there is no need for this numerous columns in the `select` clause to demonstrate the issue you are facing).

Comment: Answer is correct. Issue was with using wrong id. Thank you for the support

Answer (score 0):

Move `AND cover_photo.thumbnail=true` to `ON` clause expression:

```sql
... 
FROM organization  
LEFT OUTER JOIN cover_photo ON cover_photo.idcover_photo = organization.idorganization 
                           AND cover_photo.thumbnail=true 
WHERE organization.idorganization_type =1 
HAVING distance < 20
```

The condition by a column from right table in LEFT JOIN (except checking this column for NULL directly or indirectly and null-safe compare) ejects all rows where left table have no matching row in right table. But the difference between INNER and LEFT joins is these left-without-right rows - i.e. the condition converts LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN.

So this condition must be placed to ON clause - it will be checked/applied before joining.